# How to make my code stops when conditions are met

Tags: python, if-statement

```
for i in range(len(employeesChosen)):
    info = get_employee_info(employeesChosen[i])
    event_done=False
    if employeesChosen[i] not in currentEmployees and check_employee_availability(service,employeesChosen[i],currentStart,currentEnd,currentStart,calendarEnd):
        event_done=True
    else:
        for event in events:
            if employeesChosen[i] == event['summary']:

                if str2datetime(currentStart) == str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) == str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                    event_done = False

                if str2datetime(currentStart) < str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):  #rdv avant un qui est deja set
                    event_info = {'location': get_company_location(event['description']),'datetime': event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    start_first_event = {'location': get_company_location(event['description']),'datetime': event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    event_fabricant_info = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant),'datetime': currentStart}
                    end_second_event = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant),'datetime': currentEnd}
                    if check_event_possibility_if_before(event_info, event_fabricant_info, end_second_event, start_first_event, info[0]):
                        event_done = True
                    else:
                        event_done = False

                if str2datetime(currentStart) > str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) or str2datetime(currentEnd): #rdv apres un qui est deja set
                    event_info={'location': get_company_location(event['description']), 'datetime': event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    start_first_event ={'location': get_company_location(event['description']), 'datetime': event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    event_fabricant_info = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant), 'datetime': currentStart}
                    end_second_event = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant), 'datetime': currentEnd}
                    if check_event_possibility(event_info, event_fabricant_info, end_second_event,start_first_event, info[0]):
                        event_done=True
                    else:
                        event_done=False
```

I'm having some issues I hope you guys will help resolve. I'm new to python so please forgive my question if it already been answered a couple times.

I would like to know, below the statement

```
if employeesChosen[i] == event['summary']:
```

, how to make every  `if` run only once? Right now, even if the first condition is `False`, it will keep on running until the end. I would like the code to only lock on one of the `if` conditions. The `for` will loops 3 times.

Comment: So you want an `elif`?

Comment: check the documentation of `elif`

Comment: i tried : if , elif, else. But the last else is not working and giving me syntax error @Austin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the keyword "continue" to break the loop; Alternatively, you can use a the keywords elif/else;

for "continue":

```
for event in events:
    if employeesChosen[i] == event['summary']:
         if ....(conditions):
              event_done = False
              continue // if you want to stop here

         if ...(conditions):
              continue
         if ...(conditions):
              continue
```

This continue will stop the loop from finishing when runned

for if else loop:

```
for event in events:
    if ...(conditions):
    elif ...(conditions): // will run this if the above condition does not match, will run code after else, if no return, "continue" or "break" keyword
    else: // will run this if none of the above matches, will run code after else, if no return
```

The above code demonstrates how you can "skip" ifs with elif and else

Hope this helps